# Failed to click on a button available on a webpage using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've been trying to figure out any way to click on a button visible as ***`Download base consolidada`*** on this [webpage](https://www.anbima.com.br/pt_br/autorregular/matriz-de-probabilidade-de-resgates.htm). The button appears to be within an iframe. It seems I've been able to switch to that `iframe` and locate the element of that button using some xpath that I've defined within the following script. However, the script throws some error when it comes to click on that button.

I'm trying with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://www.anbima.com.br/pt_br/autorregular/matriz-de-probabilidade-de-resgates.htm"

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
  wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
  driver.get(link)
  wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe")))))
  wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='textRun'][.='Download base consolidada']"))).click()
```

This is the error I get:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="textRun" style="font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold; color: rgb(0, 135, 202);">...</span> is not clickable at point (345, 90). Other element would receive the click: <rect x="4.02685069008783" y="1.961104140526976" width="244.63136762860728" height="42.18820577164366" rx="8" ry="8" style="vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke; stroke-width: 3px; stroke: rgb(0, 149, 217); stroke-opacity: 1; fill: rgb(243, 242, 241); fill-opacity: 0;"></rect>
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.102)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00307AC3+2587331]
    Ordinal0 [0x0029ADD1+2141649]
    Ordinal0 [0x00193BB8+1063864]
    Ordinal0 [0x001C65FF+1271295]
    and so on--------------------
```

> How can I click on the aforementioned button using selenium?

Comment: In what time the frame loads? I see that it loads seldom. Most of the times, it doesn't load at all. Does it happen to you also?

Comment: I can see it loading in few seconds. It's very rare that the iframe doesn't load at all.

Comment: `app.powerbi.com’s server IP address could not be found.` this what comes most of the time after the page load, and very rarely I see the content, including `Download base consolidada`

Comment: I don't know why the script behaves otherwise on your end.  However, ***[this](https://www.loom.com/share/731979db55c74e2ba3c4c7cb0871c32f)*** is what happens when I run the exact script here.

Comment: Thanks for your video. I observed that somehow (at my end though it's bizarre if it's only at my end) that the browser content does not work properly in maximized browser mode. By taking a look at your video, I shifted to the default browser size and although it was still flaky, it was relatively better and I was able to successfully download the file by clicking on the button. Find my working code in the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
driver.get('https://www.anbima.com.br/pt_br/autorregular/matriz-de-probabilidade-de-resgates.htm')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe")))))
WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//*[@data-automation-type='visualContainerHost']//div[contains(@aria-label, 'Web URL')])[1]"))).click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

This gives me the output:

`Process finished with exit code 0` which implies that no errors and the code ran successfully.

Here is the snapshot of the file downloaded through the code:
[Excel file snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcS0p.png)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. So, it was the xpath issue. I finally decided to stick with this xpath `//*[contains(@aria-label,'download da base consolidada')]` by the way.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the element you're trying to click isn't the one accepting the actual click but the rect element instead.
Try replacing the Xpath of the span by the div containing the rect element and it should work.

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@aria-describedby='visualsEnterHint-e780d1b86be1529ccdf0']/div[3]/div/visual-modern/div/div"))).click()
```